# Developer option: Show layout bounds not working

Tags: android

A very helpful debug tool built into Android devices with Jelly Bean or later is "Show layout bounds" within the Developer Options.

I used it regularly on several devices, however I cannot get it to work on a Galaxy Nexus (Verizon). I toggle the setting and nothing changes. If I leave the developer options and return, the option has unchecked itself.

Has anyone else seen this? Anyone know of a way to get it to work for this device? It is a very helpful tool for debugging layouts!

I don't see any errors or warnings in LogCat when I try to check the option.

Thanks

Comment: I know this thread is dead but I just had this problem. Rebooting my G.Nexus fixed the problem.